# Smaller button over a big button in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton, swift4

I am new to swift and iOS development. I have created a scroll view with table view cells and image views inside cells. Each Image view has a button with same constraints. I have a fixed button in the same screen (irrespective of scroll view) and I am not sure how to achieve the click for it since every time I click on it, the background button is being clicked. I saw some solutions about disabling and enabling the buttons but in this case, I will not be sure which button will be in the background since it is a scroll view. Any help on how to solve this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't see your code, I can't tell you the exact fix but I assume that the question is how to determine the button's position in the parent view hierarchy. Every UIView has a method called `bringSubviewToFront(view:)` so if this was the case, then, you can use this method to bring your button to the front.